How to resolve the error ‘’dartaotruntime‘ Not Opened’?
I want to run flutter code in macOS. When I run the
flutter run 

command with VSCode, I get the following error:

‘dartaotruntime’ Not Opened
Apple could not verify that ‘dartaotruntime’ is free of malware that may harm your Mac or compromise your privacy.
Done Move to Trash

I could not find an answer to this on the internet.
ChatGPT suggests temporarily disabling Gatekeeper. But do I have to deal with disabling Gatekeeper every time? Is there a permanent solution?
